# Outllook add-in: custom tab not showing

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

This is my first try at using VS and VSTO, so I'm a bit lost there. I tried and made a very small add-in for Outlook 2010, which is supposed to add a custom tab to the Explorer ribbon, with 2 buttons calling macros. All my code checks in VS (no reference issue, nothing), but when I try building in debug mode, nothing shows up in Outlook...

I looked online for quite a while for an answer, found out about the RibbonType property to set on Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer (done) and the ControlIdType property to set on Custom, but it didn't change a thing.

So here I am, with no clue of what is wrong... VS shows no error, no warning, nothing, and when I try the add-in, Outlook doesn't even activate it. So: what am I missing? Do you need to see any of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting from the COM add-ins dialog in Outlook. Make sure that your add-in is enabled and not listed in the Disabled Items list.

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in when you try to debug it, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

You can read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

The next thing is the [Performance criteria for keeping add-ins enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx#ol15WhatsNew_AddinDisabling). Outlook 2013 monitors add-in performance metrics such as add-in startup, shutdown, folder switch, item open, and invoke frequency. Outlook records the elapsed time in milliseconds for each performance monitoring metric.
For example, the startup metric measures the time required by each connected add-in during Outlook startup. Outlook then computes the median startup time over 5 successive iterations. If the median startup time exceeds 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then Outlook disables the add-in and displays a notification to the user that an add-in has been disabled. The user has the option of always enabling the add-in, in which case Outlook will not disable the add-in even if the add-in exceeds the 1000 millisecond performance threshold.

Comment: I checked your link and the behaviour of Outlook when debugging; it's definitely a "soft" disabling here. From what I see in that article, though, the problem would be with the Startup event handler, but I didn't put anything there:

`code
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    End Sub
`